# Button cannot be fire after callback to front page

Tags: jquery

I have few buttons call to display in front page after retrieve data from Jquery ajax called, however the button is showed but cannot fire it behavior when clicked, I should able to get response from the button when I clicked, can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

ajax_network_programs_shortlist.php

```
$msg .= '<div style="clear:both;height:0;"></div>';
$msg .= '<div style="border:0px solid #33F;">';
$msg .= '    <div class="pg_btm" style="position:relative;text-align:right;">';
$msg .= '        <div>';
$msg .= '        <input id="btn_sendmsg" class="n_btn" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE" />&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$msg .= '        <input id="btn_remove" class="n_btn" name="remove_my_shortlist" type="button" value="REMOVE FROM LIST" />&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$msg .= '        <a href="'.WEBSITE_URL.'network.php" title="More">BACK <img src="images/arrow_right.png" class="cropped" /></a>';
$msg .= '        </div>';
$msg .= '    </div>';
$msg .= '</div>';

$msg = "<div class='data'>".$msg."</div>"; // Content for Data
```

Here is my div block in front page to show `$msg` callback:

```
<form id="form4" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <div class="inner-main_content3" id="inner-main_content3" style="padding:0;">

        <div class="data"></div>
        <div class="pagination"></div>

    </div>
</form>
```

My JQ's ajax

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#btn_sendmsg").click(function(){
            var parameters = $('#form4').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_send_message.php',
                data: parameters,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == 2){
                        alert('No Recepient Selected');

                    }else{
                        window.location = "mailto:XXX";

                    }

                    $('#form4')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });

        $("#btn_remove").click(function(){
            var parameters = $('#form4').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_remove_shortlist.php',
                data: parameters,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == 1){
                        alert("Selected video(s) removed");
                        window.location.replace("<?php echo selfURL()?>");
                    }else{
                        alert("Please select video(s)");
                    }
                    $('#form4')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });

        function loading_show(){
            $('#wait').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
        }
        function loading_hide(){
            $('#wait').fadeOut('fast');
        }                
        function loadData(page){
            loading_show();                    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_network_programs_shortlist.php",
                data: "page="+page,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#inner-main_content3").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                        loading_hide();
                        $("#inner-main_content3").html(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
        $('#inner-main_content3 .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
            var page = $(this).attr('p');
            loadData(page);

        });

        $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
            var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
            var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
            if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                loadData(page);
            }else{
                alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                $('.goto').val("").focus();
                return false;
            }

        });


    });
```

Thanks.

**Solutions:**

replaced `$("#btn_sendmsg").click(function()` with `$('#btn_sendmsg').live('click',function()`,

This is so far solved my issue.

Comment: What does the console say, any issues logging, when you click?

Comment: Console didn't show any error

Comment: I still have others data with radio input before the button, all `$msg` contents will pull to `<div class="data"></div>` in front page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the click handler to work for an element that gets loaded dynamically, then you set the event handler on a parent object (that does not get loaded dynamically) and give it a selector that matches your dynamic object like this:

```
$("#btn_sendmsg").on("click",function(){

alert('clicked');

});

$("#btn_remove").on("click",function(){

 alert('clicked');

});
```

Comment: still same, can't see any response when clicked.

Comment: place alert on that event and see weather that click event is occur or not

Comment: when I looked at the codes generates in HTML, its seem <form> is missing?!

Comment: when I have `<input id="btn_sendmsg" name="send_message" type="button" onclick="alert(\'hello\');" value="SEND MESSAGE" />`, the alert is popped!

Comment: you have written the code in jquery so for now please remove onclick event form that button ok and use `alert('hii');` on $("#btn_sendmsg").on("click",function(){ alert('hi'); }); and tell me if it alerts or not ?

Comment: that means click event is not working and please see when you click on button what error it show on console?

Comment: the console show `POST http://sitename.com/ajax_network_programs_shortlist.php   200 OK 312ms`, no error at all

Comment: @bouscher alert is not triggering when button is clicked that means click event is not occurring there must be an error

Comment: @conmen can you please edit your question and let me see what you did

Comment: the success call produces a bunch of HTML codes of data callback, but I wondering from the codes I found <form> tag is missing